# What is the best way to trim leading and trailing single quotes in pl_sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, trim

I am getting a Varchar2 variable with leading and trailing single quotes but I want to remove these single quotes, I am doing it like

```
trim(BOTH '''' FROM lastname);
```

It is giving me right result but is it a right way or is there any other way to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can't get any better than what you already proposed. So yes, this is the right way.

Using `BOTH` is not necessary as it is the default (as oppposed to the also valid `leading` and `trailing` specifiers). So, depending to your preferences (*short vs clear*) you might leave it out, so that your statement becomes

```
trim('''' from lastname)
```

Comment: Yes: in order to have a single `'` in a string that is itself delimted by two `'`, Oracle requires that single `'` to be specified as `''` so that it is possible to distinguish between the string's end an a `'`.